# Sorting a list by number of appearances and removing duplicates

Tags: python, list, sorting

For example, I have the following list, in which the number of appearances per element is:

```
apple - 3
banana - 4
orange - 2
```

the list:

```
["apple", "apple", "banana", "orange", "orange", "banana", "banana", "apple", "banana"]
```

I need to sort the list by prevalence without duplicaes, so the expected results will be:

```
["banana", "apple", "orange"]
```

I thought about creating a dictionary with each element as key, iterating over the list and then adding +1 for each time the key is found, so I will end up with an example dictionary:

```
dic = {"apple": 3, "banana": 4, "orange":2}
```

But kind of stuck about how to sort the list itself without the dupes..

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Thank you everyone, I did not have knowledge of Counter. Happy holidays!

Comment: sort your example dictionary and recreate the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "orange", "orange", "banana", "banana", "apple", "banana"]

counts = Counter(data)
result = sorted(counts, key=counts.get, reverse=True)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Comment: Or `counts.__getitem__`, which reflects exactly the process of extracting `counts[i]` for each `i` in `counts`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "orange", "orange", "banana", "banana", "apple", "banana"]

res = [k for k, _ in Counter(lst).most_common()]
# ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Comment: `list(...)` -> `[...]` (list comprehension, not applying `list()` on a generator expression)

Comment: @iBug That's when you start one way and turn the other :P good catch.

Answer (score 1):

sort a set based on the original list's counts. EDIT: As pointed out in comments, you may want to use other solutions instead if you have a lot of candidates, calling a list's count method multiple times is not optimal.

```
a = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "orange", "orange", "banana", "banana", "apple", "banana"]
sorted(set(a), key = lambda x: a.count(x), reverse = True) #reverse for descending
```

Result:

```
['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Comment: Never call `list.count()` repeatedly. That is just algorithmically bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby

L = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "orange", "orange", "banana", "banana", "apple", "banana"] # Input list

counts = [(i, len(list(c))) for i,c in groupby(sorted(L))]      # Create value-count pairs as list of tuples 
counts =  sorted(counts, key = lambda i: i[1] , reverse=True)    #sort value-count list
out = [key for key, value in counts]   #extract key
print (out)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `list` and `set`

```
a = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "orange", "orange", "banana", "banana", "apple", "banana"]
result =sorted(list(set(a)))
```

output :

```
['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```